# How to properly document properties with NumpyDoc

Tags: python, code-documentation, numpydoc

I'm managing a package which uses the NumpyDoc style, and I'm trying to properly document the setters/getters of some properties.

In particular, I'm having an issue with the fact that the documentation of the setter is ignored by python, and hence all the documentation has to go into the getter. On the other hand, having both `Returns` and `Parameters` fields does not seem very intuitive. For example one could write the documentation like this

```
class MyVector:
    @properly
    def real(self):
        """Real part of the vector.

        Parameters
        ----------
        newreal : array-like
            New values to assign to the vector

        Returns
        -------
        real : MyVector
            Real part of the vector
        """
        pass

    @real.setter
    def real(self, newreal):
        pass
```

But in doing so it becomes very confusing when and how the `Parameters` and/or `Returns` apply. E.g. it is not obvious (to me at least) that `Parameters` apply only for the setter, and `Returns` applies only for the getter.

Is there a standard way of doing this that works well with NumpyDoc as well as the various doc parsers (e.g. Sphinx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `napoleon` [example](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_numpy.html) indicates that the "standard" way is to document the `getter`, `setter` and `deleter` is in the `getter` method, indicating that the way your are doing it is correct.